# SWI-Prolog option processing

Tags: prolog

I am using SWI-Prolog and am confused why the option library would be written to give the following outputs:

```
?- option(a(A), [a=1, a=2, a(3)]).
A = 3.
?- option(b(B), [b=1, b=2]).
B = 1.
```

I would expect A=1 ...  Looking through the option library code though, this result is clearly intended ([git link](http://www.swi-prolog.org/git/pl.git/blob/HEAD:/library/option.pl#l109)), but why is this not a bug?

```
option(Opt, Options) :-                 % make option processing stead-fast
        arg(1, Opt, OptVal),
        nonvar(OptVal), !,
        functor(Opt, OptName, 1),
        functor(Gen, OptName, 1),
        option(Gen, Options),
        Opt = Gen.
option(Opt, Options) :-
        get_option(Opt, Options), !.


get_option(Opt, Options) :-
        memberchk(Opt, Options), !.
get_option(Opt, Options) :-
        functor(Opt, OptName, 1),
        arg(1, Opt, OptVal),
        memberchk(OptName=OptVal, Options), !.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says [the Name = Value syntax is deprecated](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.15%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/option.html%27%29%29) in favor of the Name(Value) syntax.

It seems reasonable this would be represented in the `library(option)` code by checking first for the preferred form.

Answer (score 4):

Since memberchk/2 (which is semi-deterministic, i.e., it succeeds at most once) is used in the code you quote, non-determinism (A=1 ; A = 2 ; etc.) seems explicitly *not* intended. If anything, contradictory options should maybe raise a domain error, no?

Comment: I think I could forgive the libraries for finding the first match in the list and ignoring subsequent matches (ie pushing a new option onto an option list that hides a later one) and being semi-det about it.  I just can't find a way to justify it searching first in the form key(value) then key=value.